# Calculus of order in an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic, elliptic-curves

This is my first time in this website.
I'm a student in master 2 ans I'm following a course about elliptic curves.
And I'm didn't really understand how to calculer the order of a function at a point P for a curve C.
(see the picture for the example)
 [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIOY7.png)

My questions are :
1) How to see Y and X like functions on K(C) ?
2) How to calculate ord(Y) on (0,0)

Thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: Does [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000409/definition-and-example-of-order-of-a-function-at-a-point-of-a-curve/2003141#2003141) answer your question?

Comment: Yes ! Sorry for the late ...

Comment: Okay, I'm going to move to close this as a duplicate of the question I linked: [Definition and example of "order of a function at a point of a curve"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000409/definition-and-example-of-order-of-a-function-at-a-point-of-a-curve)